# How to use multiply times async function in mocha tests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, async-await, mocha.js

I would like to use multiply times async `foo` function in mocha tests and try to do it like this:

```js
describe('This test', () => {
    const foo = async () => {
        const wrapper = mount(Component);
        const button = wrapper.find('button');
        button.simulate('click');
        wrapper.update();

        await new Promise(res => setTimeout(() => {
          res('');
        }, 0));
        
        wrapper.update();

        return wrapper;
    };

    it('should pass 1', () => {
        const wrapper = foo();
        console.log(wrapper.debug());
    });

    it('should pass 2', () => {
        const wrapper = foo();
        console.log(wrapper.debug());
    });
  });
```

But then output is
`TypeError: wrapper.debug is not a function`

This works fine without async await.

Can you help resolve it?

Comment: You can use a generator

Answer (score 0):

It looks like solution is:

```
describe('This test', () => {
    const foo = async () => {
        const wrapper = mount(Component);
        const button = wrapper.find('button');
        button.simulate('click');
        wrapper.update();

        await new Promise(res => setTimeout(() => {
          res('');
        }, 0));
        
        wrapper.update();

        return wrapper;
    };

    it('should pass 1', async () => {
        await foo();
        console.log(wrapper.debug());
    });

    it('should pass 2', async () => {
        await = foo();
        console.log(wrapper.debug());
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

@CodeJoe is correct,
use async await for resolving this. async always returns a promise, so await functions are there to wait for those promises to resolve or reject.

If some thing is returned from async functions, then await keyword is used to call that function and wait for the promise to resolve or reject. await is always meant for ***WAIT***

```
describe('This test', () => {
  const foo = async () => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      const wrapper = mount(Component);
      const button = wrapper.find('button');
      button.simulate('click');
      wrapper.update();

      await new Promise(res => setTimeout(() => {
        res('');
      }, 0));
    
      wrapper.update();

      resolve(wrapper);
    })
  };

  it('should pass 1', () => {
      const wrapper = await foo();
      console.log(wrapper.debug());
  });

  it('should pass 2', () => {
      const wrapper = await foo();
      console.log(wrapper.debug());
  });
});
```

Also, always try to return something from your async function to avoid resolve conflicts. If there is not something to resolve, make a new promise and return resolve.

In promises instances/ async promises, use  the following according to requirement -

```
return resolve()
return resolve(wrapper)
return reject()
return reject('Reject message')
return reject(new Error('Error message')
```